# How many CPU/GPU cores are using Azure Cognitive Services during the chosen training time?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I can choose training budget in customvision.ai in hours:
[image]

And I can see how much it cost in azure price calculator:

[image: azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator]

**But I missing information what resources I will get for this price per hour (how many CPU/GPU cores etc..?)**. I just want to understood will that training uses only CPU or GPU too, and how much.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Vision in Azure Cognitive Services is a platform service as far as I understand.  That means that billing is based on service (API) usage and not by hardware resources (number of CPU/GPU cores etc.).  [Azure's pricing documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/#purchase-options) about this service supports this.

A sample training that I performed shows results like below.  CPU/GPU usage information for that training iteration is not available on customvision.ai or Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: I think that this missing information is very important, because without it you can't compare: is it better to buy local resources and train own model, or pay for magic hours, maybe that 24 hours for 240$ will train model on 1 vCPU and 1 GPU, so then I will prefer better to use local training on my own machine. Unfortunately I think, that I I will not get answer for that question...

Answer (score 0):

It's uses GPU for the Advance Training.